# Change value of every n-th index in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I want to code something that solves this 'riddle'.

There are 24 Prisoners and everyone has their own cell. The Guard wants to give some of the prisoners some free time. Since all the doors of the cells are closed, he goes to every single one and opens them one by one. The 2nd time, he does that to every 2nd door. The 3rd time, to every 3rd door. He repeats this 24 times. If a door is closed, it gets opened. If it is opened it gets closed.

I've tried to code this on my own but I just can't get it to work.

Here is what I've written:

```
All_Doors = [True] * 24 # Closed = True, Open = False
for Door in All_Doors:
    for Guard in range(1,25):
        All_Doors[::Guard] = False if True else True

print(All_Doors)
```

I get this error: TypeError: can only assign an iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
All_Doors = [True] * 24 # Closed = True, Open = False
for Guard in range(1,25):
    for current_door in range(Guard,25,Guard):
        All_Doors[current_door-1] = not All_Doors[current_door-1]
print(All_Doors)
```

my output:

```
[False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

the answer make sense, because all the numbers which are squared of other number are closed - (1,4,9,16) indices. because they have odd number of multipliers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the correct way. Do you have any Idea to solve this without using not? If not it does not matter. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure why not to use **not**. You can use your version of code, but it makes it much less readable and clear. not is the proper way here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to assign a bool value to a list without iteration over it. What you are trying to do is to simply negate whatever the list `All_Doors[::Guard]` is. This can be done simply by using `not`

```
All_Doors = [True] * 24 # Closed = True, Open = False
for Door in All_Doors:
    for Guard in range(1,25):
        All_Doors[::Guard] = [not i for i in All_Doors[::Guard]]

print(All_Doors)
```

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

your code must be like these

```
All_Doors = [True] * 25 # Closed = True, Open = False
for Door in All_Doors:
   for Guard in range(25):
      All_Doors[Guard] = not All_Doors[Guard]

print(All_Doors)
```

try to use not instead of (False if True else True) because you want to navigate the door value no assign a new value to it if true then false else true

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is something like the following:

```
All_Doors = [False] * 24 # Closed = False, Open = True
for r in range(1,25):
    All_Doors = [True if i%r == 0 else False for i in range(1, 1+len(All_Doors))]
    print(f"Round {r}, opening only every {r}-th door", All_Doors[0:10])
```

As far as I understood you need to start with all doors closed (`False`), and then in each round open only the n-th ones. It's convenient to use the modulo operator (`%`), as it basically does the same as slicing by every n-th element. The above should give you some results like this (note I'm printing only the first 10 values in the list after each "round" of Guards opening the doors, for readability):

```
Round 1, opening only every 1-th door [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
Round 2, opening only every 2-th door [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
Round 3, opening only every 3-th door [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False]
Round 4, opening only every 4-th door [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False]
Round 5, opening only every 5-th door [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True]
```

*Note*: if you want to start with all the doors as `True`, you can just invert the `True` and `False` values in the above code.